# cannot my git get worked, what should I do

Tags: git

I'm getting following error on `git clone`:

```
git clone <url>
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'coursera-test': Permission denied"
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: where are you trying to clone it to?

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` creates a directory before putting contents into it. It looks like that you don't have write permissions in the location where you are running `git clone`.

`cd` to a different location, say `$HOME` and try `git clone` there using following steps:

```
cd
git clone <url>
```

Comment: can you please provide more detailed answer, I am a new user can you please explain step by step.

Comment: i can definitely explain better but this issue is related to the directory where you are executing the clone command.

Comment: thank you very much! I should have done this                                                                         "cd ~/ >
mkdir code>
cd code>
git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy" then ta daa!!!

Comment: Do you mind upvoting or accepting the answer? Whatever helped.  Thanks.